# WooCommerce Bookings plugin updating front end availability without admin approval?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-bookings

I'm setting up the `Woocommerce Bookings plugin` and I have noticed that the availability calendar is updated for all users as soon as one user adds a booking to their cart.

So if user A books April 1st - 15th for a given product, user B immediately sees those days as unavailable as soon as they are added to user A's cart.

I would like the ability to not have the availability updated on the front end until I have confirmed the booking.

I have checked the "Check this box if the booking requires admin approval/confirmation. Payment will not be taken during checkout" option in the product settings and it doesn't seem to have done anything.

Answer (score 0):

> I found a solution.

I have set the available number of bookings for each product to 100. That way, when a user requests a booking it only counts as a partial booking.

I updated the CSS and added some JS to make the partial bookings on the front end availability calendar look like available bookings.

The admin will manually set unavailable dates on each product after confirming bookings.